# Set meta viewport tag for Joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla-2.5

I need to disable the ability of the mobile browsers to zoom in/out for one of the tabs of my main menu. I am running Joomla 2.5. I tried installing the Simple Mobile Detection extension , however this ruined all my tabs URLs. So is there any way to set the meta viewport tag in Joomla ?

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using Joomla built in `setMetaData` function, like so:

```
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();
$doc->setMetaData('viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no');
```

This will set the scale to 100% (default) and disable the ability to zoom in

Comment: girlintech - You're welcome. However please bare in mind, as @Seth has mentioned in his answer, even though it's possible, a very bad idea to do this.

Answer (score 4):

As @lodder answered you *can* set this meta to prevent zooming, and that is the correct way to do it, but **you shouldn't do this**.

Disabling native browser accessibility functions is a really bad idea, a clear ‘F%$K YOU!’ to your users. No-one *needs* to disable browser zoom.

Why not disable mouse clicks as well? Exactly. It's not very friendly to deliberately hobble a users device is it? If your design breaks when a user zooms, you should *fix your design*, not cripple standard user interactions.

Here's what the Accessibility Project has to say about this (mis)usage of the viewport meta: [Never use maximum scale=1](http://a11yproject.com/posts/never-use-maximum-scale/).

This quote, from [an article](http://bradfrost.com/blog/post/fuck-you/) by [Brad Frost](http://bradfrost.com/), puts a more human, and more direct, face on it I think:

> Next time you find yourself intentionally depriving someone an experience—to acquire knowledge, to complete a task, to do something online that can make their life even just a little better—picture yourself standing in front of that person in real life, looking them square in the eyes, then firmly and definitively saying “Fuck you.”

Bottom line is some people *rely* on browser zoom, and even those that don't expect it to be there. Don't take that away please.

Comment: `Disabling native browser accessibility functions is a really bad idea, a clear ‘F%$K YOU!’ to your users. No-one needs to disable browser zoom. ` .... +1

Comment: Thank you both for pointing this out. However , I am using Joomla with OpenLayers 3 and having browser zooming and map zooming just ruins everything. I will try to find another work around though to avoid user unfriendliness.